# ResourcesNotFoundException after return of an intent to another app

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-fragments, android-intent

I am developing an Android App and I generate some `PDF` files in it. Once they are generated I start an `Intent` to an App to display the `PDF` (Like Acrobat).

Once I press the return key to return to my App, it crashes with the following error on a `Samsung Galaxy S5` with the normal `Android 5` modified by Samsung:

```
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): Process: (my package), PID: 1515
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout-v21/adapter_historie.xml from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f04001e
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:3953)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:3900)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:2149)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:413)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at (my package).adapter.HistorienAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(HistorienAdapter.java:52)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at (my package).adapter.HistorienAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(HistorienAdapter.java:1)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5223)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4449)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4359)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1370)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:562)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2900)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16550)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5303)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16550)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5303)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16550)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5303)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16550)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5303)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2102)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1956)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1865)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16550)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5303)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16550)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5303)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2102)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1956)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1865)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16550)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5303)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16550)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5303)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2102)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1956)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1865)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16550)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5303)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16550)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5303)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2312)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2025)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1180)
11-05 17:04:29.876: E/AndroidRuntime(1515):     at android.view.ViewRo
```

or with this stacktrace on an `Google Nexus 5` with `Cyanogenmod 12.1`:

```
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636): Process: (my package).vaz, PID: 22636
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout-v21/adapter_historie.xml from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f04001e
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2843)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2798)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1143)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:412)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at (my package).vaz.adapter.HistorienAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(HistorienAdapter.java:51)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at (my package).vaz.adapter.HistorienAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(HistorienAdapter.java:1)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5223)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4449)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4359)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1370)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:562)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2900)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
11-06 19:47:45.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22636):    at android.view.ViewR
```

(the full trace can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/aRuiMD8d))

at this part of my code

```
public HistorienAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.adapter_historie, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(layout);
}
```

I start the `Intent` inside of an `android.app.Fragment` like this:

```
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);

Intent viewintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
viewintent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
getActivity().startActivity(viewintent);
```

Comment: Looks like your .APK file is missing a resource file. It should be in `res/layout-v21/adapter_historie.xml`. Not sure how you've managed that, though. Do you have some kind of custom build system that may have caused this?

Comment: @SnildDolkow that is impossible. Before starting the Intent, the layout gets loaded correctly. Everything works finde. Just when I return from the other App, then it crashes, so the layout has to be in the .apk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I develop the App together with Pinguin895 and found the solution for our problem after the great answer from Snild Dolkow that we should try-catch the Exception.

I have try-catched the "android.content.res.Resources.NotFoundException" and got this stacktrace with the wanted caused by included:

```
11-07 09:54:08.912: I/AppCompatDelegate(689): The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's
11-07 09:54:11.581: W/System.err(689): java.lang.RuntimeException: Assetmanager has been closed
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:501)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2825)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2798)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1143)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:412)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at (my package).vaz.adapter.HistorienAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(HistorienAdapter.java:53)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at (my package).vaz.adapter.HistorienAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(HistorienAdapter.java:1)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5223)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4449)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4359)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1370)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:562)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2900)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-07 09:54:11.582: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
11-07 09:54:11.583: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5891)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
11-07 09:54:11.584: W/System.err(689): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout-v21/adapter_historie.xml from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f04001e
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2843)
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2798)
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1143)
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:412)
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at (my package).vaz.adapter.HistorienAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(HistorienAdapter.java:53)
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at (my package).vaz.adapter.HistorienAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(HistorienAdapter.java:1)
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5223)
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4449)
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4359)
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1370)
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:562)
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2900)
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-07 09:54:11.585: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
11-07 09:54:11.586: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
11-07 09:54:11.587: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
11-07 09:54:11.587: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5891)
11-07 09:54:11.587: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
11-07 09:54:11.587: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
11-07 09:54:11.587: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
11-07 09:54:11.587: W/System.err(689):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
11-07 09:54:11.587: W/System.err(689):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-07 09:54:11.587: W/System.err(689):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-07 09:54:11.587: W/System.err(689):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-07 09:54:11.587: W/System.err(689):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)
11-07 09:54:11.587: W/System.err(689):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-07 09:54:11.587: W/System.err(689):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-07 09:54:11.587: W/System.err(689):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
11-07 09:54:11.587: W/System.err(689):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
11-07 09:54:11.587: W/System.err(689): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Assetmanager has been closed
11-07 09:54:11.587: W/System.err(689):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:501)
11-07 09:54:11.587: W/System.err(689):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2825)
11-07 09:54:11.587: W/System.err(689):  ... 70 more
```

After some research about the information that the Assetmanager has been closed. I found that the assetmanager shouldn't be closed, because an android app need that for accessing the included files (like layout xml files) inside the .apk

In our app we used the assetmanager to pick a pdf file which is located inside the apk at the assets folder. After some input of text, the changed pdf was saved on sdcard.

```
try (AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
     InputStream is = am.open(vaz.getDatei() + ".pdf");
     OutputStream targetOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {

     /*
     *[SOME CODE FOR GENERATION AND SAVING]
     */

     Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);

     Intent viewintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     viewintent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
     getActivity().startActivity(viewintent);

} catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

We used try-with-resources for java.lang.AutoCloseable
After the return from the PDF-Viewer-App the assetmanger was already closed, because of java.lang.AutoCloseable

The fix was to put the assetmanger outside of the try-with-resources:

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();

try (InputStream is = am.open(vaz.getDatei() + ".pdf");
     OutputStream targetOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {

     ...

} catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thank you for your efforts Snild Dolkow!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first of all, what device (and software version) is this? It appears the Resources.java file has lots of added code compared to vanilla Android; your callstack mentions `Resources.java:3900` and `Resources.java:3953`, but [the official version of that file](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/res/Resources.java) only has 2859 lines. It may be that the manufacturer of your device has been patching into the Resources class (most likely to add theming support), and messed something up.

Anyways, I think I've identified the corresponding lines in the official code:

[`Resources.java:2776`](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/res/Resources.java#2776):

```
2774            getValue(id, value, true);
2775            if (value.type == TypedValue.TYPE_STRING) {
2776                return loadXmlResourceParser(value.string.toString(), id,
2777                        value.assetCookie, type);
2778            }
```

...and 53 lines later at [`Resources.java:2829`](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/res/Resources.java#2829)

```
2785    /*package*/ XmlResourceParser loadXmlResourceParser(String file, int id,
2786            int assetCookie, String type) throws NotFoundException {
2787        if (id != 0) {
2788            try {
2789                // These may be compiled...
2790                synchronized (mCachedXmlBlockIds) {
2791                    // First see if this block is in our cache.
2792                    final int num = mCachedXmlBlockIds.length;
2793                    for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
2794                        if (mCachedXmlBlockIds[i] == id) {
2795                            //System.out.println("**** REUSING XML BLOCK!  id="
2796                            //                   + id + ", index=" + i);
2797                            return mCachedXmlBlocks[i].newParser();
2798                        }
2799                    }
2800
2801                    // Not in the cache, create a new block and put it at
2802                    // the next slot in the cache.
2803                    XmlBlock block = mAssets.openXmlBlockAsset(
2804                            assetCookie, file);
2805                    if (block != null) {
2806                        int pos = mLastCachedXmlBlockIndex+1;
2807                        if (pos >= num) pos = 0;
2808                        mLastCachedXmlBlockIndex = pos;
2809                        XmlBlock oldBlock = mCachedXmlBlocks[pos];
2810                        if (oldBlock != null) {
2811                            oldBlock.close();
2812                        }
2813                        mCachedXmlBlockIds[pos] = id;
2814                        mCachedXmlBlocks[pos] = block;
2815                        //System.out.println("**** CACHING NEW XML BLOCK!  id="
2816                        //                   + id + ", index=" + pos);
2817                        return block.newParser();
2818                    }
2819                }
2820            } catch (Exception e) {
2821                NotFoundException rnf = new NotFoundException(
2822                        "File " + file + " from xml type " + type + " resource ID #0x"
2823                        + Integer.toHexString(id));
2824                rnf.initCause(e);
2825                throw rnf;
2826            }
2827        }
2828
2829        throw new NotFoundException(
2830                "File " + file + " from xml type " + type + " resource ID #0x"
2831                + Integer.toHexString(id));
2832    }
```

Now, if I'm not missing anything, I see two possible ways to reach line 2829:

1. Have an `id` of 0
2. Get a `null` `XmlBlock` back from `mAssets.openXmlBlockAsset()`

Option #1 is obviously not the case, as we can see from your exception print that your id is `0x7f04001e`.

So that leaves the second option. Well, let's check [the code for `AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset()`](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/res/AssetManager.java#479):

```
479    /*package*/ final XmlBlock openXmlBlockAsset(int cookie, String fileName)
480        throws IOException {
481        synchronized (this) {
482            if (!mOpen) {
483                throw new RuntimeException("Assetmanager has been closed");
484            }
485            long xmlBlock = openXmlAssetNative(cookie, fileName);
486            if (xmlBlock != 0) {
487                XmlBlock res = new XmlBlock(this, xmlBlock);
488                incRefsLocked(res.hashCode());
489                return res;
490            }
491        }
492        throw new FileNotFoundException("Asset XML file: " + fileName);
493    }
```

I don't see a way that this code can return `null`. It'll either return a `new XmlBlock`, or it'll throw an exception.

So maybe I didn't find the right lines after all -- there is a similar `NotFoundException` thrown at `Resources.java:2821`, but in that case, you should have a "caused by" line in your exception stack (granted, it seems to cut off in your question, so maybe there is..?). Seems unlikely that the code would've been modified to move that exactly to the expected offset from the other line, though...

Maybe try running your code in the emulator/AVD instead of on your device, and see if you get the same bug there? If you can't reproduce the problem there, I think we'll have to conclude that your device manufacturer has messed something up in the resource loading code.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer! I have tried it out on 2 different devices. First on an Samsung Galaxy S5 with Android 5 and then on an Google Nexus 5 with Cyanogenmod 12.1.

Comment: [Cyanogenmod 12.1's Resources.java file](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/caf/cm-12.1/core/java/android/content/res/Resources.java) doesn't have that many lines, either. Would you update your post with the callstack from there as well, please? And you might as well add the *full* callstack for the Samsung, too. Including any "Caused by" stacks, if they exist.

Comment: I have added the second stack trace. I also tried to get the full callstack, but what i pasted here was the only thing I could get from LogCat. If there is a way to get a more detailed version, I would be glad to hear it

Comment: Okay, now we're getting somewhere! [This file](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-12.1/core/java/android/content/res/Resources.java) seems to be the right one (it matches the line numbers from your CyanogenMod stack trace). And it appears it's not the throw location I though, but actually the one with the cause. Which means that we most likely need the full stack (including the "caused by") to figure out what's wrong. You should be able to get it by running `adb logcat -d -bcrash`.

Comment: I have added a link a pastebin containing the full trace generated by the cyanogenmod phone. Do you still need the one from the Galaxy s5?

Comment: It's still cut off: `E/AndroidRuntime( 6752):  at android.view.ViewRo`. But since you have lines following it, I guess you're not the one cutting it off. Alright, let's try to catch the NotFoundException. Since you're not going to keep this code, you can just try-catch all Exceptions. Then, use something like this: `int num=0; do { Log.i("PinguinDebug", "Exception #" + (++num), ex); ex=ex.getCause()}`. You'll have to forgive any syntax errors, since I'm writing this on the fly, but you get the idea. That should print multiple exceptions, which will hopefully let us figure out what's going on.

Comment: Catching the Exception was a great idea. Even if it was no Problem with the Resources.java files, it helped my friend, who developes the App with me, to find the solution for our problem. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd be very interested to hear what the problem was. Feel like sharing? :)

Comment: Look at my friend's answer. He posted a quite detailed description :)